# Fine-Uploader preview images before upload - FileReader

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

this issue relates to Widen Fine-Uploader ( https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader )

I'd like to show a preview of images before upload starts. No Autoupload. Multiple File Selector - no single file-input elements.

```
.on('submitted', function(event, id, filename) {
    $('<img id="pprev'+id+'" src="#" />').appendTo("#previewupload"+id);
    readURL(this,id);     // WHAT DO I NEED TO USE FOR THIS ?
}

...
manualuploader.fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
```

and

```
function readURL(input, previewID) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#pprev'+previewID)
            .css("border","10px solid #FF0000")
            .attr('src', e.target.result);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

what param do I need to use in readURL() initialization?

Comment: I can't try with fine uploader, but **this** must be the input element object, take a look at this simple fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/un7ua/

Comment: nope. **this** does not work here.

Comment: In your function this is not the input, you must get it and pass it to the function, take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/un7ua/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to pass any `File` object that represents an image into your `readURL` method.

So, first off, change the last line of your `readURL` function to `reader.readAsDataURL(file)`.  Also, change the first parameter, for readability, from `input` to `file`.

You can obtain the `File` object for a specific Fine Uploader file ID via the `getFile` API method.  You can retrieve the `File` in your `submitted` callback like this:

`$(this).fineUploader('getFile', id);`

Then, as I said, pass the result of this call (a `File`) into your `readURL` method after making the suggested modifications.

Note that native support for displaying previews pre-upload is a [scheduled feature](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/214), but, as you can see, this is not very difficult to do right now, thanks to Fine Uploader's API.  Also note that the `getFile` API method does not work in non-File API browsers, such as IE9 and earlier.